# Vuetify Next - How to change the color of placeholder text according to the selected theme

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm creating a component based on Vuetify autocomplete. But I need to change the color of the placeholder according to the selected theme.

I mean, if the theme is dark, the placeholder color must be `#cccccc`, if the theme is light placeholder color must be `#000000`;

I've tried to use some selectors like:

```css
.v-text-field input::placeholder{
 color: #000000;
}
```

But I wasn't able to achieve the expected result.

Here is my **SFC**

```html
<template>
    <VAutocomplete variant="solo" class="placeholderColor" placeholder="Example text" />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts"></script>
<style scoped>
.placeholderColor .v-input__control .v-field .v-field__field .v-field__input input {
    color: blue !important;
}
</style>
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the below solution could do the job.

1. Give a class to the autocomplete element and toggle it according to the selected theme. For instance-

```
<v-autocomplete
  :class="$vuetify.theme.name == 'dark' ? 'dark-placeholder' : 'light-placeholder'"
  v-model="values"
  :items="items"
  placeholder="I am a placeholder"
></v-autocomplete>
```

2. On the CSS side, use `::placeholder` selector-

```
<style>
.dark-placeholder ::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: #cccccc !important;
}
 .light-placeholder ::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: #000000 !important;
}
</style>
```

Here is a working demo. Try toggling the theme and you should see that for the `dark theme`, the placeholder color is `yellow` and for the `light theme`, the placeholder color is `red`.

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'light'
  }
})

const app = createApp({
  template: '#app-template',
  data: () => ({
    items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
    values: null,
    value: null,
  }),
  computed: {
    isDarkTheme() {
      return this.$vuetify.theme.name == 'dark'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTheme() {
      this.$vuetify.theme.name = this.$vuetify.theme.name == 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
    }
  }
}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
.dark-placeholder ::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: yellow !important;
}
 .light-placeholder ::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.2/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
  <v-app>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="8">
            <v-autocomplete
              :class="isDarkTheme ? 'dark-placeholder' : 'light-placeholder'"
              v-model="values"
              :items="items"
              placeholder="Default"
            ></v-autocomplete>
          </v-col>
          <v-col>
            <v-btn @click="toggleTheme" :color="isDarkTheme ? 'yellow' : 'red'">toggle theme</v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
  </v-app>
</script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: In a few moments i'll test it and mark as an answer